# If Else statement to generate pdf and send email based on the form responses

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to make if else statement based on the form responses. I create 2 spreadsheet. So, I want after form submit, it will go to different spreadsheet and generate the pdf and send the email. I try to do below if else but the pdf not generate and email not send. Can anyone help me?

```
function afterFormSubmit(e) {
  const info = e.namedValues;
  const info1 = e.namedValues;
  const pdfFile = createPDF(info);
  const pdfFile1 = createPDF1(info1);
  const entryRow = e.range.getRow();
  const entryRow1 = e.range.getRow();
  
  const ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("All");
  const ws1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Animal");
  
  var type = ws.getDataRange().getRow(6);
   
      if (type == "11"){
     
          ws.getRange(entryRow, 7).setValue(pdfFile.getUrl());
          ws.getRange(entryRow, 8).setValue(pdfFile.getName());
        
          sendEmail(e.namedValues['Email Address'][0],pdfFile);
        
      } else if (type == "22") {
          ws1.getRange(entryRow1, 7).setValue(pdfFile1.getUrl());
          ws1.getRange(entryRow1, 8).setValue(pdfFile1.getName());
        
          sendEmail(e.namedValues['Email Address'][0],pdfFile1);
      }   
}

function sendEmail(email,attachment){
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, "Here is Your PDF", "Your PDF is attached.", 
                    {attachments: attachment,
                     name:'My Company'});
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your google sheet file so that the community may have a clear view on the situation

Comment: First there is no method Range.getRow(6), only getRow().  This is probably throwing an error.  Instead it should probably be `var type = ws.getRange(6,1,1,ws.getLastColumn());`.  Then type is a 2D array so in your if statements it should be something like `type[0][0[ == 11`.